# Fourier antitransform using scaling property?

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to calculate the antitransform of:

$\frac{1}{2\cdot(1+5w)^2}$

Now I know the antitransform of $\frac{1}{(1+5w)^2} = t \cdot e^{-5t} u(t)  $

But in this case I got that divided by 2. I assumed I had to use the scaling property which says:

$F[f(ax)] = \frac{1}{|a|} \hat{f}(\frac{w}{a})$

Now I'm not really sure how to apply this. Could anyone help?

Comment: Scaling property only applies is you multiply the time/frequency variable. In this case, you only need to multiply the inverse with 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h(t)$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $H(\omega)$, then by linearity the inverse Fourier transform of $aH(\omega)$ is simply $ah(t)$. This has nothing to do with the scaling property you mentioned, because the latter refers to the scaling of the *argument* of the function.